# Neo4j Spark using graph frames

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, graphframes

I recently started using the Neo4j-Spark-Connector and went through some of the examples provided in this link https://neo4j.com/developer/apache-spark/. Everything seemed to work until I tried working with graphframes. When I run the following:

`val gdf = Neo4jGraphFrame.fromGraphX(sc,"Person",Seq("KNOWS"),"Person")`

I get the error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Do you have those labels (Person) and rel-types "KNOWS" actually in your database?

Comment: Yea, both Person and KNOWS are in the database, spelled exactly as such.